# Why does jQuery Mobile Simple Dialogue freeze when users click too fast?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile

I am using simpledialog2 to create dialogue boxes in my jQuery Mobile application.

At least in Google Chrome, if a user opens a dialogue box by clicking on one of the list view items, closes it, and immediately opens another, dialogue boxes no longer open when the user clicks on list items.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shanabus/ykHTa/4/)

Why?

Here is my HTML.

```
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">bar</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">baz</a></li>
</ul>​
```

and Javascript.

```
$(function() {

    // When user clicks on a list item, produce a dialogue/alert box.
    $('[data-role="listview"] a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('<div>').simpledialog2({
                mode: 'blank',
                headerText: "Popup title",
                headerClose: true,            
                dialogForce: true,
                blankContent: 
                "My message to you."
        });
    });
});
```

​

Answer (score 0):

One of the main differences between writing with regular jQuery and jQuery mobile is that you use

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
  // code here
});
```

instead of

```
$(function() { 
  // code here
});
```

Not sure how to fix your specific issue, but a good start would be to change the when you're loading the code for a site written in jquery mobile.